# Не работает backspace в EditText после пробела

Tags: android, android-edittext

В приложении перестают удаляться буквы после того, как ввести пробел. Самое странное, что это наблюдается только в одном EditText, в остальных все нормально. В чем может быть проблема?

UPD разметка:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/comment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/addComment"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/addComment"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addComment"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/addComment"
    android:hint="@string/enter_comment" />
```

Comment: ну так `TextChangedListener` добавлен к этому `EditText` если да, то в нем и кроется проблема

Comment: @ermak0ff, так дело в том, что никаких обработчиков не добавлено к нему. Единственное, что с ним делаю - это getText и setText

Comment: ну а в разметке у него что?

Comment: @ermak0ff добавил разметку